# Logstash not running with filebeat

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm following the digital ocean guide to installing the ELK stack. It was running, but now I am running into problems with logstash.

When I run to debug, I get this::

```
tail -f /var/log/logstash/logstash.log 

{:timestamp=>"2017-02-10T10:38:05.169000-0500", :message=>"Error: Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 1, column 1 (byte 1) after "}
{:timestamp=>"2017-02-10T10:38:05.201000-0500", :message=>"You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can\nuse to validate logstash's configuration before you choose\nto restart a running system."}
{:timestamp=>"2017-02-14T10:51:46.921000-0500", :message=>"fetched an invalid config", :config=>"input {\n  lumberjack {\n    port => 5044\n    type => syslog\n    ssl_certificate => \"/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt\"\n    ssl_key => \"/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key\"\n  }\n}\n\ninput {\n  beats {\n    port => 5044\n    ssl => true\n    ssl_certificate => \"/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt\"\n    ssl_key => \"/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key\"\n  }\n}\n\nfilter {\n  if [type] == \"syslog\" {\n    grok {\n      match => { \"message\" => \"%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}\" }\n      add_field => [ \"received_at\", \"%{@timestamp}\" ]\n      add_field => [ \"received_from\", \"%{host}\" ]\n    }\n    syslog_pri { }\n    date {\n      match => [ \"syslog_timestamp\", \"MMM  d HH:mm:ss\", \"MMM dd HH:mm:ss\" ]\n    }\n  }\n}\n\ninput{\n  beats {\n    port => 5044\n  }\n}\n\noutput {\n  elasticsearch {\n    hosts => \"10.84.234.224:9200\"\n    manage_template => false\n    index => \"%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}\"\n    document_type => \"%{[metadata][type]}\"\n  }\n}\n\noutput {\n  elasticsearch {\n    hosts => [\"localhost:9200\"]\n    sniffing => true\n    manage_template => false\n    index => \"%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}\"\n    document_type => \"%{[@metadata][type]}\"\n  }\n\u007Fstdout { codec => rubydebug }\n}\n\noutput {\n  elasticsearch { host => localhost }\n  stdout { codec => rubydebug }\n}\n\ninput {\n  tcp {\n    port => 5400\n    type => syslog\n  }\n  udp {\n    port => 5400\n    type => syslog\n  }\n}\n\nfilter {\n  if [type] == \"syslog\" {\n    grok {\n      match => { \"message\" => \"%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}\" }\n      add_field => [ \"received_at\", \"%{@timestamp}\" ]\n      add_field => [ \"received_from\", \"%{host}\" ]\n    }\n    date {\n      match => [ \"syslog_timestamp\", \"MMM  d HH:mm:ss\", \"MMM dd HH:mm:ss\" ]\n    }\n  }\n}\n\noutput {\n  elasticsearch { hosts => [\"localhost:9200\"] }\n  stdout { codec => rubydebug }\n}\n\n\n", :reason=>"Expected one of #, if, \", ', } at line 56, column 1 (byte 1278) after output {\n  elasticsearch {\n    hosts => [\"localhost:9200\"]\n    sniffing => true\n    manage_template => false\n    index => \"%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}\"\n    document_type => \"%{[@metadata][type]}\"\n  }\n", :level=>:error}
```

However, I tried to delete my lumberjack confs and I can't find a problem in any of my configs. Does anyone know if there is a way to do a fresh reinstall of logstash. I think I've messed with too many confs, logstash, logstash-forwarder, etc.

Conf file:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { 
    host => ["localhost:9200"]
    sniffing => true
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
When I run a configtest, I get this error:

```
sudo service logstash configtest

/etc/init.d/logstash: 156: /etc/init.d/logstash: /opt/logstash/bin/logstash: not found
```

Comment: "fetched an invalid config" Please [edit] to show the actual config file

Comment: output, elasticsearch should be `hosts` not `host`. Are you sure you copied the config from the right tutorial?

Comment: And your error says `input {\n  lumberjack`, so this is not the file you think you are running.

Comment: right, but I got rid of my lumberjack file and I don't know how to tell it to read from this file

Comment: Read the documentation? `logstash -f` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/command-line-flags.html

Comment: And you want to `sudo service logstash stop` while you debug your scripts.

Comment: Just added an update. I also try to stop, but it says logstash stop/waiting

Answer (score 0):

Note that logstash as a service is reading **all** files from `/etc/logstash/conf.d`, so if you edit just one, that doesn't mean it'll reload and fix the other files.

I'm not sure what file you are editing, but you have many files that logstash is appending together.

For example, one file has this

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5400
    type => syslog
  }
  udp {
    port => 5400
    type => syslog
  }
}
```

Another has this

```
input{
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
```

And so on... so, check all files in `/etc/logstash/conf.d` for errors individually using `logstash --configtest`, as the error says.

---

If you look at the end of your error message...

> :reason=>"Expected one of #, if, \", ', } at line 56, column 1 (byte 1278) after ...
>
> ```
> output {
>   elasticsearch {
>     hosts => [\"localhost:9200\"]
>     sniffing => true
>     manage_template => false
>     index => \"%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}\"
>     document_type => \"%{[@metadata][type]}\"
>   }
> ```

Looks like you are missing a closing bracket for `output {}`, or something on line 56 is bad / missing, it thinks.

---

I'm not sure what is wrong with `configtest`, but you do not need a service for that. The command `logstash --configtest` can test your files itself.

Comment: I have a closing bracket. There is 2 at the end, I'm a missing something? Also, if my conf files are all in /etc/logstash/conf.d and I edit it, how can I tell logstash to reload?

Comment: `sudo service logstash restart` will attempt to run all the configs again. In the file shown, yes, you do. In the error message that contains `input {\n lumberjack`, no you do not.

Comment: I've done logstash restart, but it says stop: unknown instance.

Comment: I also don't know where that lumberjack file is coming from so I'm unable to edit it. Sorry I'm new to logstash and elk stack

Comment: Run `ls /etc/logstash/conf.d` and you'll see all the files. If the service cannot stop an instance, then that's a Linux issue, not a logstash issue

Comment: there is no lumberjack file there, but maybe that is becuase the service never restarted. Therefore, I need to figure why the service can't be stopped because my guess is my conf's aren't being reloaded

Comment: Command `ps aux | grep logstash` will tell you about processes that (still) exist

Comment: output: `username+ 12495  0.0  0.0  15944  2260 pts/2    R+   09:12   0:00 grep --color=auto logstash
` But I don't how to kill it. No commands I've tried will stop it. It just keeps saying stop/waiting

Comment: There's only grep running. Theres no logstash processes.

Comment: no still not working. Now, my filebeat is not sending logs to logstash to view in kibana.

Comment: I would recommend you test your logstash configuration better by sending data to the `stdout`, and not immediately `elasticsearch`.